# Firefox "send tab" across different profiles?

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile, firefox-sync

I would like to keep my work profile and private profile on Firefox mostly separate (bookmarks, stored logins, browsing history), but still be able to send tabs between devices.

Is such a thing possible in current versions of Firefox?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I would like to send tabs between my work and personal profile

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez Sadly no. Though I am anyway back to using Chrome, and PushBullet as separate service. It also allow to keep things separate by adding the work account as a "friend", but then you can't send from the work device to a *specific* home device, only to all of them.

Comment: It seems as if this doesn't work using the Tab Mover extension or even via drag & drop

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

- install the add-on "Tab Session Manager" for both of your Firefox profiles (work and personal)
- eg. on your work profile: save one or a bunch of tabs using TSM to a session
- in TSM right-click on the just saved session. Export.
- this puts a json-file on your local hard disk
- then switch to your personal profile: open the settings of TSM, Sessions, Import sessions, browse to your json-file
- done

Yes, it it tedious, but it works. And you can transfer as many tabs as you want.

Comment: The question was not intended to handle migration of large sets of tabs but rather about Firefox's "send tab" feature. The sole purpose of such features is to make things less tedious, so that solution doesn't really work here.